# ASP.net MVC Multiple Select item in ListBoxFor issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my Model :

```
public partial class TAUX
    {
        public short CAT_ID { get; set; }
        public int C_GARANT { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Taux est obligatoire")]
        public decimal POURC_TAUX { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DATE_EFFET { get; set; }
        public int TAUX_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual CATEGORIE CATEGORIE { get; set; }
        public virtual GARANTIE GARANTIE { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> SelectItems { set; get; }
    }
```

This is my Controller :

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CAT_ID = new SelectList(db.CATEGORIE, "CAT_ID", "LIBELLE");
            ViewBag.C_GARANT = new SelectList(db.GARANTIE, "C_GARANT", "LIB_ABREGE");
            return PartialView("_Create");
        }
```

This is my View :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="Categorie">Categorie : </label>
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectItems, "CAT_ID")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CAT_ID)
         </div>
```

And this the error That I got :

```
Error 1 :'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<pfebs0.Models.TAUX>' does not contain a definition for 'ListBoxFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.ListBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' has some invalid argument
Error   2: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'
```

What I'm trying to do is getting all data from `Categorie` Tabel and put it in `ViewBg.CAT_ID`.
Then In my View I have a `listBox` filled with Item From `ViewBag.CAT_ID`, and the selected Value Will be set in `SelectItems`.

Comment: try my code and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the issue.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectItems, "CAT_ID")
```

The second argument should be the select list rather than a string, so it should be like

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectItems, (ViewBag.CAT_ID as SelectList))
```

OR

```
@{
 var list = ViewBag.CAT_ID as SelectList;
}

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectItems, list )
```

Comment: This Work fine but I'm getting other error now See my update :D

Comment: Please change the code as well which you tried so far so that we can figure out the issue.

Comment: I fixed the error See my Update on your post. thank you so much.

Comment: @Chlebta - I updated the code of Jitendra accordingly. Editing an answer is not necessarily the right tool to communicate with the author - prefer comments instead. However fixing a little typo is fine if it is obvious. I replaced `model.CAT_ID` by `model.SelectItems` because it is obvious from your original code.

Comment: @Chelbta - ... presuming that `model.SelectItems` is the property that the user will change by using the listbox. It is a bit confusing because `SelectList` sounds as if it was the list of available items to select from. The items that the user selected could be better named e.g. as `SelectedCategoryIDs`.

Comment: @chiccodoro thank's :D just I added `new { size = 2}` but the size of the list box dosn't change do you know why ?